# How to access authentication tokens during claim injection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

During AuthenticationEvents (OIDC) I stored some data in the AuthenticationProperties, since that was the place I thought it to be practical (namely i stored the Adal Token Cache there, which might or might not be a good idea).

Then I use a claim transformation, which will add the user profile claims from another service. That service will use OAuth-Bearer-Authentication. The token required for the bearer-authentication is retrieved from the AuthenticationProperties, by calling `httpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync(_sharedAuthOptions.SignInScheme, tokenName);`

Now the fun part: `GetTokenAsync()` will call `AuthenticationManager.Authenticate()`, which will then try to run my claim injection, which will try to contact the service, which needs the oAuth-Bearer-Token, which will call `GetTokenAsync()`, which will call `AuthManager.Authetnicate()`, which will then run my claim injection, etc. etc. (StackOverflowException - yay)

Some code snippets:
*Saving the tokens*

```
public static async Task<AuthenticationResult> AuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
{
    var clientCred = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientId, context.Options.ClientSecret);

    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(context.Options.Authority, false, new TokenCache());
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.ProtocolMessage.Code,
        new Uri(context.Properties.Items[OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey]), clientCred, context.Options.Resource);

    var authToken = SerializeCache(authContext.TokenCache);

    var properties = new List<AuthenticationToken> { authToken };
    context.Properties.StoreTokens(properties);

    return result;
}
```

*Reading the tokens*

```
await httpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync(_sharedAuthOptions.SignInScheme, AdalTokenCacheName);
```

Now the questions:
Is there a way to access the AuthenticationProperties without rerunning the auth-pipeline?
If not is there a good way to save additional data to the generated principal claims?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was pretty easy.
I originally wanted to make sure, that the tokenCaches existance was coupled to the lifetime of the authentication session. For some reason I thought it was a good idea to save that into the aforementioned properties.
I would not do that again. Just save the data into the claims and everything will work like a charm.